# How to compare the message of object in ChangeListener

Tags: javafx, treeview

The following code is to show treeview and printout the value that user selected.
I'd like to printout the "OK" that means same value of object "oval" in ChangeLisner method'S argument.

How should I do?

I refer to the following url

http://blog.professional-webworkx.de/javafx-get-selecteditem-of-treeview/

and I add code as the following:

```
if("TreeItem [ value: SubItem ]".equals(oldVal)){System.out.println("YES");}
else{System.out.println("NO");}"
```

The result of System.out.println is the following:

> TreeItem [ value: SubItem ]
>
> NO

```
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String>("root");
        final TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(item);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Item" + i));
                if(i%5==0) {
                TreeItem<String> subItem = new TreeItem<String>("SubItem");
                item.getChildren().add(subItem);
                subItem.setExpanded(true);
                for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                    subItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("SubsubItem" + i));
                }

            }

        }
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldVal, Object newVal) {
                System.out.println(oldVal);// + " neuer: " + newVal);

                if("TreeItem [ value: SubItem ]".equals(oldVal)){System.out.println("YES");}
                else{System.out.println("NO");}
            }
        });
        stage.setTitle("TreeView");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(treeView, 640, 480));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare the `toString` of the tree item; compare its value. (And **do not** use raw types: properly type all your variables and anonymous classes, etc.)

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> observable, TreeItem<String> oldItem, TreeItem<String> newItem) {
        System.out.println(oldItem.getValue());// + " neuer: " + newVal);

        if(oldItem != null && "SubItem".equals(oldItem.getValue())){ 
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
});
```

Of course, this is much cleaner using lambda expressions (and taking advantage of Java 8 type inference):

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldItem, newItem) -> {
        System.out.println(oldItem.getValue());// + " neuer: " + newVal);

        if(oldItem != null && "SubItem".equals(oldItem.getValue())){ 
            System.out.println("YES");
        } else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much . you've been so helpful！